# How to write a line as the sum of a vector and a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $L$ be the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the equation $y=x+1$. Find a vector $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L = \vec{u} + W$.

I know that $L = \vec{u} + \vec{u}'$ for some $\vec{u} \in W$ and $\vec{u}' \in W^{\perp}$ and I think that property is relevant to solving this problem.

But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the parameterised form $x\mapsto (x,x+1)=x(1,1)+(0,1)$ then $W={\rm gen}\{(1,1)\}$ and $u=(0,1)$.